# When Rails require mod_rails, what about Django, TurboGears, Symfony, CakePHP? Can they deploy using mod_python and mod_php?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, cakephp

When Rails applications seem hard to deploy (or used to be), what about Django, TurboGears, Symfony, CakePHP -- can they be simply deployed using mod_python or mod_php?  Actually, won't it need something like a mod_django so that the code can run in a "Django" environment?  (Just like Rails' `script/console` or Rails 3's `rails console`)

Answer (score 3):

Django applications can certainly be deployed with minimum fuss using `mod_python`.

That said, experienced people will [tell you](http://www.technobabble.dk/2008/aug/25/django-mod-wsgi-perfect-match/) to use the more lightweight and efficient `mod_wsgi` instead of `mod_python`. This too can be done with minimum effort. I have done it on multiple occasions and app deployment was always the least of my worries.

**Update**

@Rebus has it right:

> mod_python is not being actively developed anymore, use mod_wsgi

Comment: mod_python is not being actively developed anymore, use `mod_wsgi`.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to deploy a Django site. See the [Django Docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/deployment/) or the [Django book](http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter12/). As mentioned `mod_python` is dead and `mod_wsgi` is the recommended method. Another method which has been making more noise lately is [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/). You can see [Eric Holscher's blog post](http://ericholscher.com/blog/2010/aug/16/lessons-learned-dash-easy-django-deployment/) about how easy the deployment can be with it.

Answer (score 0):

For CakePHP if you have a standard PHP installation, you probably, at most, only need to load mod_rewrite. This module is often included in the build, though.